# deis images with dependencies of etcd have error executing bin/boot script: "waiting for etcd at :4001..."

Tags: vagrant, docker, coreos, deis, etcd

I'm building a **Deis** cluster with 3 nodes on CoreOS as recommend the [Readme Section](https://github.com/deis/deis#boot-coreos) with Vagrant, but when I execute: `make run` some error occur on **registry.service**. After some time inspecting deis/image, I found that all image with dependencies of `etcd` have the same problem, all images fail or still waiting on execution of `bin/boot` script. The output:

```
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
waiting for etcd at :4001...
```

Anybody know, what the problem?

Comment: Is this you? https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/1653 If so, we'll help you in that GitHub thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using the last Stable version of CoreOS ([367.1.0](https://coreos.com/releases/#367.1.0)). And when the **services** with dependencies of **etcd** have parameters like this: `-e HOST=$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4` the HOST value are empty.

On CoreOS version [367.1.0](https://coreos.com/releases/#367.1.0) you need use: `${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}` to work fine. However, I finally update my Vagrant with dependency of 402.2.0 box version of CoreOS and all look fine without `{}`.